# Удалить часть строки от конкретного символа до конкретного символа

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка

```
var last_filter = 'filter=liked&search-tag=art&';
```

Я хочу удалить от слова `filter` до ПЕРВОГО знака `&`

То что у меня есть сейчас, удаляет все от filter до ПОСЛЕДНЕГО знака `&`.

```
var last_filter = last_filter.replace(/filter.*&/, '');
```

Comment: `.*` — «жадный» (захватывает всё, что может), `.*?` — «ленивый», останавливается у первого &.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Большое вам спасибо!